# Use abstract environment from other document class

Tags: koma-script, abstract

I am using the KOMA-scrartcl class at the moment for compiling multiple single papers into a combined document. Now I'd like to switch over to the scrreprt class (I'd like to use chapters), but for this class the abstract environment is differently defined. Is there an easy way to get the same settings for an abstract in scrreprt class as they are in the scrartcl class (e.g. narrower text width, abstract directly after the title not on the next page).

Here a short test example for the scrartcl class:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
{\LARGE{One}}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

vs. here for the scrreprt class

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
{\LARGE{One}}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The code for `abstract` in the two classes is identical. The difference is in the default value of titlepage, so you want

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false]{scrreprt}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried David's method and though it does what we want, I found that for me it broke some aspects of the title page for me. Specifically, I found that the page with `\maketitle` puts the page number at the bottom.

So, I have renewed the `abstract` environment to remove the `if` condition of checking for title page and always using the non-titlepage abstract. This is simply the code between lines 2836 and 2868 of the `scrrept.cls` file (`File: $Id: scrkernel-version.dtx 2215 2015-10-06 09:50:41Z kohm $`).

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
\if@abstrt
    \small
    \begin{center}
      {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname
        \vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}
\fi
    \quotation
}{%
\endquotation
} 
\makeatother
```

Sample output is shown in the image.

[image: Screenshot of Output]